# Contextual meaning of "afforded to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to Merriam Webster Dictionary, *afford* has two meanings:

1. to be able to bear the cost of
2. to make available, give forth, or provide naturally or inevitably

In what contexts are the two meanings appropriate?

Is the use of *afforded to* in the following phrase correct?

> Growth prospects **afforded to** employees of your firm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase you quoted is grammatically correct and makes use of the second meaning you listed - "growth prospects *made available* to employees of your firm".

The context usually does make the meaning clear for this word. For example, the following sentence reads horribly but the meaning of the word is easy to understand both times:

`The company could not afford to afford additional benefits to employees`

Answer (score 0):

The word "afforded" is synonymous with "granted", or "given to". example: Legal assistance may be granted to (afforded to),the defendant.